# @media queries doesn't work well on mobile browsers

Tags: html, css, mobile, responsive-design, media-queries

I am trying to build a responsive website using media queries (like [Microsoft website](http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/default.aspx)), for desktop, mobile phone and tablet. The `meta tag` and `media queries` are written as below:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">


    @media only screen and (min-device-width:320px) and (max-device-width:720px), only screen and (min-width:320px) and (max-width:720px) {
     /*-- this is for mobile --*/
    hide C, show A, D
    }

@media only screen and (min-device-width:721px) and (max-device-width:1023px), only screen and (min-width:721px) and (max-width:1023px) {
          /*-- this is for tablet --*/
          hide B, show A, C
}
@media only screen and (min-device-width:1024px), only screen and (min-width:1024px)  {
          /*-- this is for desktop --*/
          show A, B, C. hide D
}
```

It works well on desktop and tablet, but not on mobile phone. I have tested  this website on Android phone and Windows phone, it seems that on mobile phone, some pages in this web site perform good, others are kind of like combination of mobile version and tablet version. For example the menu bar. In the mobile version, the menu bar in every page should show A, D and hide C (see the code above). But it shows A, C, D in some pages (and A, C in tablet style ), and shows A, D on some other pages.

When I changed the media queries into:

```
@media only screen and (min-device-width:320px) and (max-device-width:720px) {
 /*-- this is for mobile --*/
hide C, show A, D
}

@media only screen and (min-device-width:721px) and (max-device-width:1023px)
          /*-- this is for tablet --*/
          hide B, show A, C
}

@media only screen and (min-device-width:1024px) {
          /*-- this is for desktop --*/
}
```

Then problem solved, it seems that the browsers on mobile phone have mixed up the tablet version and the mobile version of this website. But in this way, I cannot test the website on desktop browser.
How can I solve this problem?

Comment: @media only screen and (max-width:1024px)

Comment: *-device-width isn't recommended... "The difference is subtle but very important..."
"...using *-device-width can prevent content from adapting on desktops or other devices that allow windows to be resized because the query is based on the actual device size, not the size of the browser window."https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/layouts/rwd-fundamentals/use-media-queries?hl=en#a-note-on-min-device-width

Comment: You are right, but *-width do not work on phones and tablets. I have to use *-devoice-width to let the website work on phones and tablets.

Comment: @user3794582 you do not need device-width you need to have the viewport meta tag in your html. Also, consider taking a course in responsive design. http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/articles/quick-tip-dont-forget-the-viewport-meta-tag--webdesign-5972 http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/beginners-guide-to-responsive-web-design

Comment: @Christina Thanks for your suggestion, I will try to add the viewport rule in CSS later. BTW, I do have put meta tag in <head> (I have put it above).